# Database polling with Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have to query a database in a timely fashion to know the state of a legacy system. I've thought of wrapping the query around an `Observable`, but I don't know the correct way to do it.

**Basically, it will be the same query every 5 seconds.** But I'm afraid I will have to face these problems:

- What if the execution of the query takes 10 seconds? I don't want to
  execute any new query if the previous is still being processed.
- Also, there should be a timeout. If the current query doesn't execute
  after, for example, 20 seconds, an informative message should be
  logged and a new attempt (the same query) should be sent.

Extra details:

- The query is just a `SELECT` that returns a dataset with a list of status codes (*working*, *faulted*).
- The Observable sequence will always take the latest data received from the query, something like the Switch extension method.
- I would like to wrap the database query (lenghty operation) into a Task, but I'm not sure if it's the best option.

I'm almost sure that the query should be executed in another thread, but I have no idea of how the observable should look like, ever  having read [Introduction to Rx by Lee Campbell](http://introtorx.com/).

Comment: Can you add more details? What data does the query get back? does the query return a single object? in the case of timeout you say you want a new query to be launched, what is that query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a fairly classic case of using Rx to poll another system. Most people will use `Observable.Interval` as their go-to operator, and for most it will be fine.

However you have specific requirements on timeouts and retry. In this case I think you are better off using a combination of operators:

- `Observable.Timer` to allow you to execute your query in a specified time
- `Timeout` to identify and database queries that have overrun
- `ToObservable()` to map your `Task` results to an observable sequence.
- `Retry` to allow you to recover after timeouts
- `Repeat` to allow you to continue after successful database queries. This will also keep that initial period/gap between the completion of the previous database query and the commencement of the next one.

This working [LINQPad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQPad) snippet should show you the query works properly:

```
void Main()
{
    var pollingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    var dbQueryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    //You will want to have your Rx query timeout after the expected silence of the timer, and then further maximum silence.
    var rxQueryTimeOut = pollingPeriod + dbQueryTimeout;

    var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) { Name = "DatabasePoller" });

    var query = Observable.Timer(pollingPeriod, scheduler)
                    .SelectMany(_ => DatabaseQuery().ToObservable())
                    .Timeout(rxQueryTimeOut, Observable.Return("Timeout"), scheduler)
                    .Retry()    //Loop on errors
                    .Repeat();  //Loop on success

    query.StartWith("Seed")
        .TimeInterval(scheduler)    //Just to debug, print the timing gaps.
        .Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private static int delay = 9;
private static int delayModifier = 1;
public async Task<string> DatabaseQuery()
{
    //Oscillate the delay between 3 and 12 seconds
    delay += delayModifier;
    var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(delay);
    if (delay < 4 || delay > 11)
        delayModifier *= -1;
    timespan.Dump("delay");
    await Task.Delay(timespan);
    return "Value";
}
```

The results look like:

```
Seed 00:00:00.0125407
Timeout 00:00:15.0166379
Timeout 00:00:15.0124480
Timeout 00:00:15.0004520
Timeout 00:00:15.0013296
Timeout 00:00:15.0140864
Value 00:00:14.0251731
Value 00:00:13.0231958
Value 00:00:12.0162236
Value 00:00:11.0138606
```

The key part of the sample is....

```
var query = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), scheduler)
                .SelectMany(_ => DatabaseQuery().ToObservable())
                .Timeout(rxQueryTimeOut, Observable.Return("Timeout"), scheduler)
                .Retry()    //Loop on errors
                .Repeat();  //Loop on success
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a further explanation of how to arrive at this solution. https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Repository/Polling.md

Comment: Is the main purpose of using the EventLoopScheduler here to make sure the query runs on the same thread? Is this the best way to go when polling another system using RX?

Comment: Correct, that is the intent here. In this case I would suggest doing so just so that you are not competing with the Task/Thread Pool. As I name the Thread in this example, most logging product will also expose that too. However using an EventLoopScheduler here is not mandatory, Rx will maintain serialization of work.

Comment: Updated to include link to sample code with workings to arrive at implementation

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you should do:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
    from ds in Observable.Amb(
        Observable.Start(() => /* Your DataSet query */),
        Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0))
            .Select(_ => new DataSet("TimeOut")))
    select ds;
```

This triggers a new query with an interval **between** executions of 5 seconds. It's not 5 seconds since the last one started, it's 5 seconds since the last one ended.

Then you try your query, but you `.Amb` it with a timer that returns a special `DataSet` after 10 seconds. If your query finishes before 10 seconds is up then it wins, but otherwise the special `DataSet` is returned. The `.Amb` operator is basically a "race" operator - the first observable to produce a value wins.

Comment: Wow, the combination of observables is quite impressive! You mean that both observables will race and Amb will get the first to come. What loses me is the to 2 nested from clasues. Is that part the one that permits the part that in which you say "This triggers a new query with an interval between executions of 5 seconds. It's not 5 seconds since the last one started, it's 5 seconds since the last one ended."?

Comment: @SuperJMN - Thanks. The `Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))` only fires after 5 seconds after all subscribers have finished their work. So if the second part of the query is working the interval won't fire until 5 seconds after it is done.

Comment: I _think_ as you are using `SelectMany` to consume your `Observable.Interval` that is nothing _blocking_ the consumption, so it will tick every 5 seconds, i.e. not once the DB query has finished.

Comment: The code in this answer can also execute overlapping queries. i.e. Database queries that take longer than 5.0 seconds will start to execute while the previous query is still running.

Comment: @LeeCampbell - I like that you included testing code with you answer. I've pinched your testing code and have been trying it against my code and you're right. I'll have to fiddle a bit with my answer.