# Observable sequence that polls repository until a valid value is returned

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have to poll a database until it contains *valid* data.

To do it, I have a repository that should queried every `n` seconds in order to get a my very own entity, called `DestinationResponse`.

```
class DestinationResponse 
{
     bool HasDestination { get; set; }
     bool Destination { get; set; }
}
```

When the DestinationResponse has its property `HasDestination` to `true`, the `Destination` is returned.

So, my observable sequence should get all the responses waiting for one to have `HasDestination=true`. It basically awaits for a response that HasDestination set to true. When this happens, it returns it and the sequence completes. It will only push **one** element at most!

My current approach is this:

```
var pollingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(n);

var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) {Name = "DestinationPoller"});

var observable = Observable.Interval(pollingPeriod, scheduler)                
    .SelectMany(_ => destinationRepository.GetDestination().ToObservable())
    .TakeWhile(response => !response.HasDestination)
    .TakeLast(1)
    .Select(response => response.Destination);
```

I know I's wrong, mainly because the Interval call will keep generating even if the last call to GetDestination hasn't finished.

**NOTE:** 
`repository.GetDestination()` returns a `Task<DestinationResponse>` and it actually queries the database.

Comment: Seems like a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714408/database-polling-with-reactive-extensions/33739633?

Comment: I think it's slightly different since it will only poll until a valid value is found and then, the sequence will complete. I don't know how to mix Timer and Repeat to make it work like "keep polling until you get a valid response, return it and complete yourself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging the answer from [Database polling with Reactive Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714408/database-polling-with-reactive-extensions/33739633) with your example code, I think gives you what you want.

```
var pollingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(n);

var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) {Name = "DestinationPoller"});

var query = Observable.Timer(pollingPeriod , scheduler)
    .SelectMany(_ => destinationRepository.GetDestination().ToObservable())
    .TakeWhile(response => response.HasDestination)
    .Retry()    //Loop on errors
    .Repeat()  //Loop on success
    .Select(response => response.Destination)
    .Take(1);
```

Comment: Lee, I'm sorry, but I have tried the query and it doesn't work as expected. The observable only gets the first response that does NOT have destination (HasDestination = false). I want to do the opposite: getting the very first that has destination. And to get only one element.

Comment: I have just flipped the TakeWhile predicate, is that what you want now?

Comment: I believe that TakeWhile will make the sequence to stop when a response that doesn't has a destination comes. I have tried with this (please, see my auto-answer below!)

Answer (score 0):

This code may be the query I want. What do you think?

```
private IObservable<Destination> CreateOrderDestinationObservable(string boxId, int orderId)
{
    var pollingPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DestinationPollingDelay);
    var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler(ts => new Thread(ts) {Name = "DestinationPoller"});

    var observable = Observable.Timer(pollingPeriod, scheduler)
        .SelectMany(_ => externalBridgeRepository.GetDestination(boxId, orderId).ToObservable())
        .Where(response => response.HasDestination)
        .Retry()
        .Repeat()
        .Take(1)
        .Select(response => response.Destination);

    return observable;
}
```

Comment: Um, I dont think you need both `Interval` and `Repeat`. Probably `Timer` and `Repeat`. But seems fine. You unit test should tell you if it works properly.

Comment: Oopps, sorry! I made a mistake. I used Interval instead of Timer.